# flyway against azure: user permission creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, flyway

We use FlyWay as a migration tool to manage our database version.
Recently we added two stored procedures in repeatable scripts, one of which uses user defined types (`CREATE TYPE`). The other calls the former.

The account I use in my deployment script is **not** the `db_owner` on master (the account you get from the Azure portal). Instead, I created a separate deployment account on the database in question, initially only as `db_ddladmin`, and now upgraded to `db_owner` so that it can `GRANT EXEC` on the user defined types.

However, the second procedure consistently fails when I try to run the migration using this account:

```
Migration R__21Proc_ConflictsForUI.sql failed
---------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : I/O Error: Connection reset
Location   : ./db/Stored Procedures/R__21Proc_ConflictsForUI.sql
Line       : 5
Statement  : CREATE PROC Conflicts_For_UI @CustomerId INT, @TotalRows  INT = 20
```

When I try to run the same migration using my portal `db_owner` account that is also on master, it works.

Why would Azure close the connection on the second procedure, but not the first?

Comment: So it's not not the EXEC proc that fails, but CREATE proc fails?

Comment: Correct. We have an IF EXISTS at the top of the script that drops the proc first. That works. This is why the error is reported on line 5.

Answer (score 0):

By doing just `GRANT EXEC` you gave the permission on execution, but to be able to `CREATE PROC` that REFERENCES UDT, a user should have `REFERENCES` permission on UDT.

Alternatively you can grant `CONTROL` on UDT that will bring to user

- `REFERENCES`
- `EXECUTE`
- `VIEW DEFINITION`
- `TAKE OWNERSHIP`

on UDT

Comment: According to this article https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189612(v=sql.105).aspx, `db_ddladmin` already has the `REFERENCES` permission. Could this be different on Azure than on SQL Server instances? Or does it not apply to UDT by default?

Comment: Also note that, the first `CREATE` stored procedure script is successfully applied. This is the one that references the UDTs directly (as parameters to the procedure). The second `CREATE` procedure simply calls the first procedure and passes normal table variables as parameters. This is the one that fails with the connection reset error.

Comment: I did not understand about WHAT account you wrote: >>> I created a separate deployment account on the database in question, initially only as db_ddladmin, and now upgraded to db_owner so that it can GRANT EXEC on the user defined types<<<  I understood that your db_ddladmin is used to GRANT some permissions and not to create procs, you wrote it became db_owner now so if you use it not to grant permissions but to execute your create scripts it just should not have any problem at all

Comment: This still appears to be a difference between server-level permissions and database-level permissions then, and I can't find any reason for it.

Comment: To manipulate UDT you do not need any server level permission. DB_owner can manipulate any database object. But you still did not answer what are effective permissions of the user that have problems. You wrote about ddl_admin that only grants permissions, then you wrote you upgrade it to db_owner, and he has no problem at all, then you write about someone with permissions problem but who is this someone? ddl_admin? db_owner? None of ddl_admin/db_owner but someone who was granted only EXECUTE permission on the UDT?

Comment: So on Azure you get an `sa` login which you can see in the portal dashboard for that database resource. This is what I referred to with >>>not the db_owner on master (the account you get from the Azure portal).<<<, and with >>> portal `db_owner`<<<. Everything works using this account. But it is not the account I _want_ to use for automated deployments, so I setup a separate account for use by flyway, which has `db_ddladmin` permissions at first, but for which I now also granted `db_owner` permissions. This migration does not work when I use this database account.

Comment: Can it bee that you launch your script without changing database context? So instead of your database you try to execute your script in master? Db_owner has all the possible permissions in database, but if you run script in other database it fails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158143/discussion-between-henk-roux-and-sepupic).